# How can I set the data into a template dynamically?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I have a list of Task objects.
I have a template which contains a modal form to edit a task.
When a user clicks the link to a single Task I want to set the task to be edited to the Task that was clicked and then render the form.

I'm trying it with reactive variables and Tracker.depend. But I haven't quite gotten it working yet. The data on Template.taskUpdateForm doesn't get set properly.

Please see this commit to see what I'm working on.
https://github.com/laran/eisenhower/commit/e89890d49f5b772849d09fd1f719a6cdafa58125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on a task to edit, just store it's _id or the whole task in a Session variable, and in the helper function for your modal use that same session variable. No need to worry about Tracker depend. This always works for me.

Comment: That worked. I also got my other code working though. I was setting the selectedTask to the wrong thing. I just needed SelectedTask.set(this.task) instead of SelectedTask.set(this).

Comment: Great. Why don't you mark the answer as correct then, so others can easily find it.

Answer (score 0):

I was setting the selectedTask to the wrong thing. I just needed SelectedTask.set(this.task) instead of SelectedTask.set(this)